How can I call a code-behind method from javascript in Blazor
I have a Blazor application, and at some point I need to call my component's code behind method.
In javascript:
         DotNet.invokeMethodAsync('MyAssembly', 'MyAssembly.Components.Orders.Checkout.PlaceOrderAsync', paymentToken)
            .then(result => {
                // Handle success
                console.log('C# method PlaceOrderAsync() called successfully.');
            })
            .catch(error => {
                // Handle error
                console.error('Error calling C# method PlaceOrderAsync():', error);
            });

In Blazor component code-behind:
namespace MyAssembly.Components.Orders
{
    public partial class Checkout : CustomOrderingComponentBase
    {
         ...
        [JSInvokable("PlaceOrderAsync")]
        public async Task PlaceOrderAsync(string versapayToken)
        {
        ...

I get an error upon DotNet.invokeMethodAsync():
Error: System.ArgumentException: The assembly 'MyAssembly' does not contain a public invokable method with [JSInvokableAttribute("MyAssembly.Components.Orders.Checkout.PlaceOrderAsync")].
What am I missing?

@Yogi thank you very much! I used the docs you referred me to and was able to make it work. If you make this an Answer, I will mark it.
